# Computing all Tic-Tac-Toe moves

Tags: haskell, tic-tac-toe

Recently I started to learn Haskell. I did this by making exercises on the Internet. The problem of making these exercises is that I never know if I solved it the correct way. I currently wrote a function which I think looks really ugly, but I don't know how to improve it. I hope that someone could give me some tips to improve it.

In this exercise I need to make a [Tic-Tac-Toe game.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe)

The question of the function I wrote is as follows:

> Exercise 8. Write a function `moves :: Player -> Board -> [Board]` that,
>   given the current player and the current state of the board, returns
>   all possible moves that player can make expressed as a list of
>   resulting boards. (For now, you should continue making moves, even if
>   one of the players has already won.)

I wrote the following code:

```
moves :: Player -> Board -> [Board]
moves p ((a,b,c),(d,e,f), (g,h,i)) = (moves' a (((symbol p),b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' b ((a,(symbol p),c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' c ((a,b,(symbol p)), (d,e,f), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' d ((a,b,c), ((symbol p),e,f), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' e ((a,b,c), (d,(symbol p),f), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' f ((a,b,c), (d,e,(symbol p)), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' g ((a,b,c), (d,e,f), ((symbol p),h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' h ((a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,(symbol p),i))) ++
                                     (moves' i ((a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,(symbol p))))

moves' :: Field -> Board -> [Board]
moves' c m = if c == B then [m] else []
```

Is there a way to improve my code?

Comment: I did not know it exist. I will ask it there. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I will do that next time.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you can use a where binding to clear this up:

```
moves :: Player -> Board -> [Board]
moves p ((a,b,c),(d,e,f), (g,h,i)) = (moves' a ((s,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' b ((a,s,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' c ((a,b,s), (d,e,f), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' d ((a,b,c), (s,e,f), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' e ((a,b,c), (d,s,f), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' f ((a,b,c), (d,e,s), (g,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' g ((a,b,c), (d,e,f), (s,h,i))) ++
                                     (moves' h ((a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,s,i))) ++
                                     (moves' i ((a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,s)))
    where
        s = symbol p
```

Next, I would recommend changing your `Board` type to use a flat list instead of nested tuples, it's a lot easier to work with:

```
type Board = [Field]
```

For whatever your `Field` type is (for future reference please include all relevant definitions in your questions on SO, this goes for any language).  Now you can write this a bit differently:

```
moves :: Player -> Board -> [Board]
moves p [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i] = moves' a [s, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i] ++
                                      moves' b [a, s, c, d, e, f, g, h, i] ++
                                      moves' c [a, b, s, d, e, f, g, h, i] ++
                                      moves' d [a, b, c, s, e, f, g, h, i] ++
                                      moves' e [a, b, c, d, s, f, g, h, i] ++
                                      moves' f [a, b, c, d, e, s, g, h, i] ++
                                      moves' g [a, b, c, d, e, f, s, h, i] ++
                                      moves' h [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, s, i] ++
                                      moves' i [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, s]
    where
        s = symbol p
```

Now I recognize a `zipWith` here between the first and second arguments to `moves'`, although we'll need a `concat` after the `zipWith` is done:

```
moves :: Player -> Board -> [Board]
moves p board@[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]
    = concat
    $ zipWith moves'
        board
        [[s, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i],
         [a, s, c, d, e, f, g, h, i],
         [a, b, s, d, e, f, g, h, i],
         [a, b, c, s, e, f, g, h, i],
         [a, b, c, d, s, f, g, h, i],
         [a, b, c, d, e, s, g, h, i],
         [a, b, c, d, e, f, s, h, i],
         [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, s, i],
         [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, s]]
    where
        s = symbol p
```

Now, this still leaves the big block of different boards.  There is definitely a pattern here.  If you have a `replace` function with the type `replace :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]` (I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader) then you could write this as

```
[replace 0 s board,
 replace 1 s board,
 replace 2 s board,
 replace 3 s board,
 replace 4 s board,
 replace 5 s board,
 replace 6 s board,
 replace 7 s board,
 replace 8 s board]
```

Or more simply

```
map (\i -> replace i s board) [0..8]
```

So your entire function becomes

```
moves p board
    = concat $ zipWith moves' board
    $ map (\i -> replace i s board) [0..8]
    where
        s = symbol p
        replace i a xs = undefined
        moves' B m = [m]
        moves' _ _ = []
```

Comment: If you make `i` the last argument to `replace`, then you can partially apply it instead of using a lambda (note that currently, the order in the application does not match that implied by the un-definition).

Comment: @pat I thought about it, but `replace` is a pretty general use case function and then it would just look weird to me with the index as the last argument.  I don't think it's a terrible thing to have to use a lambda now and again.  Thanks for spotting that typo, I've got that fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explaination! I think your way is much better than mine! There is only one problem for me. There is huge part of code already written for me, so if I change the type I need to change all the code. My purpose was only to improve my ownfunction. Sorry for not telling! When I am done with the whole exercise, I am going to improve it with your solution.

Comment: @maffh Yeah, the real key here is switching from nested tuples to a list for the board type, it's just a lot easier to work with with lots of built-in functions.  In some ways it's more harmful since you can create boards with the wrong number of elements, but this can be alleviated by using a `newtype` wrapper along with a `mkBoard :: [Field] -> Board` function which ensures that you have only 9 `Field`s.  However for an exercise like this one there isn't much of an issue.